In Next.js how to navigate to a page with url params?
I'm using Next.js with TypeScript and I want to navigate to a new page and want to include the URL parameters as well. How do i do that?
For example I'm at http://localhost:3000/ and I want to navigate to http://localhost:3000/path?queryParam=value by clicking on a button.

You can achieve this by combining the usePathname, useRouter and the useSearchParams hooks.
"use client"

import { usePathname, useSearchParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const SomeComponent = () => {
   const pathname = usePathname();
   const { push } = useRouter();
   const searchParams = useSearchParams();

   const onClickHandler = () => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);

      if (queryParam) {
         params.set("queryParam", encodeURIComponent("some value"));
      } else {
         params.delete("queryParam");
      }

      push(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`); //You can use the replace method if you want to replace the history

   }

   return (
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Go to URL</button>
   )
}





You can only do this on a component rendered on client side,
so you need to include 'use client' on the top of your component.
Use the useRouter hook from next/navigation.
Instantiate a new URLSearchParams.
Set all URL parameters to the new URLSearchParams.
Use the router.push function to navigate to the new page, including the given parameters.

For example:
'use client'
 
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
 
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set("queryParam", "value");

        router.push(`/path?${params}`);
      }}
    />
  )
}

Sources:

Next.js useRouter
MDN Web Docs URLSearchParams

